# pytest-ing a class method that doesn't return

Tags: python, pytest

I'm designing a python class that essentially only has `__init__` and `run` methods. Basically, the class is created from a `__main__` script, `run()` is called and never returns in normal use (it's actually listening to an `mqtt` stream and executing external programs depending on the mqtt message).

I can test the creation on the pbject and the functionality of the `__init__` method, but I can't see how to test `run`.

```
class Dispatcher:
   def __init__(self, master, topic):
      self.master = master
      self.topic = topic

   def run():
     # create mqtt object
     # connect to master and subscribe to topic
     while True:
        # poll for message and take appropriate action
```

Comment: can you please share some code, it would make it easier for folks to answer the question

Comment: In general you want to test whether your class provides the right outputs given a set of inputs. If `run` listens to a stream (and presumably does something with the stream input) then you would need to check whether the class can receive the stream and do something useful with it.

Comment: The code doesn't really exist, but I'll have a go.

Comment: You mock the message queue, send prepared messages and verify appropriate actions were performed by invoking `run`. `while True` is just a bad design - it should have an exit condition in order to be „unittestable“.

Comment: Accepted on the comment about `while true`. As I said, this was just to give an idea as the code doesn't exist yet.
I'll have to get my head about mocking - I really don't 'get' it right now.